# Csharp threading starting new threads when one finished without waiting on join

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've searched all morning and I can't seem to find the answer to this question.

I have an array of Threads each doing work and then I'll loop through the ids joining each one then starting new threads. What's the best way to detect when a thread has finish so I can fire off a new thread without waiting for each thread to finish?

EDIT added code snippet maybe this will help

```
            if (threadCount > maxItems)
            {
                threadCount = maxItems;
            }

            threads = new Thread[threadCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(delegate() { this.StartThread(); });
                threads[i].Start();
            }

            while (loopCounter < threadCount)
            {
                if (loopCounter == (threadCount - 1))
                {
                     loopCounter = 0;
                }

                if (threads[loopCounter].ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
                {
                    threads[loopCounter] = new Thread(delegate() { this.StartThread(); });
                    threads[loopCounter].Start();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Are you using .NET 4? The Task Parallel Library makes this relatively easy with continuations...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than creating new thread each time, why not just have each thread call a function that returns the next ID (or null if there's no more data to process) when it's finished with the current one?  That function will obviously have to be threadsafe, but should reduce your overhead versus watching for finished threads and starting new ones.

so,

```
void RunWorkerThreads(int threadCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
        new Thread(() => {
            while(true) {
                var nextItem = GetNextItem();
                if (nextItem == null) break;
                /*do work*/
            }
        }).Start();
    }
}

T GetNextItem() {
   lock(_lockObject) {
       //return the next item
   }
}
```

I'd probably pull GetNextItem and "do work" out and pass them as a parameters to RunWorkerThreads to make that more generic -- so it would be `RunWorkerThreads<T>(int count, Func<T> getNextItem, Action<T> workDoer)`, but that's up to you.

Note that Parallel.ForEach() does essentially this though plus give ways of monitoring and aborting and such, so there's probably no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: +1 you are describing a very simple threadpool. Thread safety can be achieved with an interlocked increment.

Comment: Sure, and in all seriousness do try to use Parallel.For/ForEach instead of my quick hack.  It's more far more robust.  Plus it's a good resume booster to have some experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the thread's `ThreadState` property and when it's `Stopped` you can kick off a new thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx

Comment: The hard bit is checking the state, specifically when to do so.

Comment: @David Heffernan, you can use a ManualResetEvent to trigger when any thread is done and then ThreadState to see which. Really though, with rhe added information you provided, there's no need to spawn new threads, go with Dax's recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Get each thread, as the last thing it does, to signal that it is done. That way there needs to be no waiting at all.

Even better move to a higher level of abstraction, e.g. threadpool and let someone else worry about such details.